# mod_rewrite capturing domain and tld

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using mod_write to rewrite this

```
www.variabledomain.variableext
```

to

```
http://my.com/variabledomain.variableext
```

Note that `variabledomain` and `variableext` are really variable, so I can't hardcode them.

I'm not an expert at mod_rewrite, but I thought something like would work, but it isn't. Any ideas what I should be doing instead.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)$ http://my.com/$2\.$3 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule%20RewriteRule) only matches on the URL path, not the hostname. You'll need to use [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond%20RewriteCond), e.g.

```
RewriteCond HTTP_HOST ([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://example.com/%2.%3/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There are more great examples on how to do similar things in the Apache documentation "[Dynamic mass virtual hosts with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/vhosts.html)". Pay particular attention to the "See Also" section on the right that has great examples.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck on this for a couple of hours and nothing seemed to work. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad it worked out